# Calculate numbers of hours from arrival time to completed time but

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an online form where a user enters the arrival time, completed time, number of hours spent, the tax and then the rate. This works fine but if we're already entering the arrival and completed time, i should be able to get the hours automatically.

Example

If a person arrives at a location at 11:00 am and leaves at 1:00 pm, the total should hours should be 2.00.

If a person arrives at a location at 5:30 pm and leaves at 7:30 pm, the total should hours should be 2.30.

I need to do this but I'm having issues:

HTML

```
      <input type="text" name="start" id="start" placeholder="start"> <br>

      <input type="text" name="end" id="end" placeholder="end" ><br>

      <input type="text" name="hours" id="hours" placeholder="hours"><br>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

          myFunction();
          $("#start, #end").on("keydown keyup", function() {
              myFunction();
          });
      });


      function myFunction() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;


         s = start.split(':');
         e = end.split(':');
         min = e[1]-s[1];
         hour_carry = 0;
         if(min < 0){
             min += 60;
             hour_carry += 1;
         }
         hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
         min = ((min/60)*100).toString()
         diff = hour + "." + min.substring(0,2);
         document.getElementById("hours").value = diff;

        }
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/w8znf0uf/2/)

Comment: Why is 5:30 -> 7:30 2.30 hours?  Isn't it 2 hours?

Comment: Are you following 24 hour time format?

Comment: What are the issues you having ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is negative numbers if the hours pass over 12:00.

Here is the code to fix it, this assumes the very next occurrence of the hour and not after. For example: 5:30 - 4:30 would be 11 hours, not 23 hours. It will think 5:30am - 4:30pm or 5:30pm - 4:30am (in your scenario it appears not to matter).

```
s = start.split(':');
e = end.split(':');
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
    s[i] = parseFloat(s[i]);
}
for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++) {
    e[i] = parseFloat(e[i]);
}
if(s[0] > e[0]) {
   s[0] = s[0] - 12;
   console.log("true");
}
```

Make sure numbers are parsed to float values just incase. Then if the start hour is greater than the end hour, subtract 12 from the start hour.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5cb7o0o/

Comment: No problem, happy coding